# visual studio c linker wrap option?

Tags: c, visual-studio, linker, cmocka

From this article [Unit testing with mock objects in C](https://lwn.net/Articles/558106/):

> This is done by using the `--wrap` linker option which takes the name of the wrapped function as an argument. If the test was compiled using gcc, the invocation might look like:
>
> `$ gcc -g -Wl,--wrap=chef_cook waiter_test.c chef.c`

How can I do this when compiling a C project in visual studio?

Comment: +1 This is what I would like to know too, it appears that in VS (i.e. MSVC compiler) you can only use #defines to manually override the actual implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `--wrap` in `ld` can be emulated by the `/ALTERNATENAME` option in MSVC Linker.

We start from two compilation units, say `foo.o` compiled from `foo.c`, whose external functions are declared in `foo.h`, and `main.o` from `main.c`.
(If `foo` has been compiled as a library, things won't change much.)

```
// foo.h
int foo();

// foo.c
int foo() {
    return 0;
}

// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"
int main() {
    int x = foo();
    printf("%s\n", x ? "wrapped" : "original");
}
```

The return value of `int foo()` is 0, so the snippet of code above will output "original".

Now we override the actual implementation by an alias: The `#include "foo.h"` in `main.c` is replaced by

```
#define foo real_foo
#include "foo.h"
#undef foo
#pragma comment(linker, "/alternatename:real_foo=foo")
```

Let me explain what happens here:

1. by `#define foo real_foo`, the function declaration in `foo.h` is modified as `int real_foo()`.
2. However, the symbol in `foo.o` is still named after `int foo()`, instead of the alias `int real_foo()`. That's why we need the `/alternatename` linker switch.
3. `"/alternatename:real_foo=foo"` tells the linker that, if you cannot find the symbol called `real_foo`, try `foo` again before throwing an error.
4. Apparently there is no definition of `int real_foo()`. MSVC Linker will search for `int foo()` and link it instead at each occurrence of `int real_foo()`.

As the previous implementation has been aliased, now we redirect `int foo()` to our new implementation by a macro:

```
int wrap_foo() {
    return real_foo() + 1;
}
#define foo wrap_foo
```

And we are done here. At last the `main.cpp` looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define foo real_foo
#include "foo.h"
#undef foo
#pragma comment(linker, "/alternatename:real_foo=foo")

int wrap_foo() {
    return real_foo() + 1;
}
#define foo wrap_foo

int main() {
    int x = foo();
    printf("%s\n", x ? "wrapped" : "original");
}
```

Built in MSVC, it will output "wrapped".