# Mocking C functions in MSVC (Visual Studio)

Tags: c, visual-studio, unit-testing, mocking, cmock

I am reading several articles on mocking C functions (like [CMock](http://www.throwtheswitch.org/cmock/), or [CMocka](https://lwn.net/Articles/558106/)), but I am not sure how the actual functions are replaced with mocked functions in this process. For example, CMocka relies on automatic wrapping using a GNU compiler, which supports parameters like `--wrap` to append the `__wrap` prefix to function calls, or *weak symbols* which allow you to override any symbol you like.

But how do you do this in Visual Studio, for pretty much all other frameworks?

For example, [CMock has an example](http://www.throwtheswitch.org/cmock/) similar to this (simplified a lot here):

```
// myfunc.c
#include <parsestuff.h>

// this is the function we would like to test
int MyFunc(char* Command)
{
    // this is the call to the function we will mock
    return ParseStuff(Command);
}
```

There is also the actual implementation, which contains the actual function the linker should find in the actual application:

```
// parsestuff.c

int ParseStuff(char* cmd)
{
    // do some actual work
    return 42;
}
```

Now, during testing the Ruby script creates mock functions like:

```
// MockParseStuff.c (auto created by cmock)

int ParseStuff(char* Cmd);
void ParseStuff_ExpectAndReturn(char* Cmd, int toReturn);
```

1. But if the VS project already includes `parsestuff.c`, how will it be possible that the call from `myfunc.c` ends up in `MockParseStuff.c`?
2. Does this mean I cannot have `parsestuff.c` included in the unit testing project? But if this is the case, then it's also impossible to mock, for example, `MyFunc` from `myfunc.c` in any tests, since I already had to include the file it in order to test it?

**(Update)** I am also aware that I can include the `.c` file instead of the `.h` file, and then do some preprocessor stuff to replace the original call, like:

```
// replace ParseStuff with ParseStuff_wrap
#define ParseStuff ParseStuff_wrap
// include the source instead of the header
#include <myfunc.c>
#undef ParseStuff

int ParseStuff_wrap(char* cmd) 
{
    // this will get called from MyFunc,
    // which is now statically included
}
```

but this seems like a lot of plumbing, and I don't even see it mentioned anywhere.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33790425/1488067) asked the specific thing about configuring the linker to wrap the functions, but I believe it's not possible in MSVC. Also, CMocka mentions this, but CMock doesn't mention this requirement at all.

Comment: Do you have to mock C-Style functions in a C++ environment, or do you have C environment only? If you can use C++, there is a very simple solution for your problem and I can provide an example.

Comment: @mrAtari: it's Visual Studio, so I can mix C++ and C, however there could be issues with certain C code not being compatible with C++ (check [this similar question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/34878/22983), for example). However, it if works most of the time, please do provide an example anyway of how C++ would solve this - especially if it can avoid adding any testing-related preprocessor directives into the production code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple and short solution with hippomocks:

I created an empty Win32 console application with

- main.cpp
- myfunc.c + myfunc.h
- parsestuff.c, parsestuff.h

and added the code from your example.

With help of hippomocks, you can mock every C-Function. Here's how my main.cpp looks like:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "myfunc.h"
#include "hippomocks.h"


extern "C" int ParseStuff(char* cmd);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MockRepository mocks;

    mocks.ExpectCallFunc(ParseStuff).Return(4711);

    char buf[10] = "";

    int result = MyFunc(buf);

    return result; //assert result is 4711
}
```

HippoMocks is a free, simple and very powerful one-header framework and can be downloaded on GitHub.

Hope I've earned the bounty :)

**UPDATE, How it works:**

1. HippoMocks gets the func pointer to ParseStuff
2. HippoMocks builds a replacement func pointer to a template function with same signature and own implementation.
3. Hippomocks patches the jmp opcode from the function call prologue in memory, so that it points to the replaced function.
4. Replacement and memory patch are released after call or in destructor.

Here's how it looks like on my machine:

```
@ILT+3080(_ParseStuff):
00D21C0D  jmp HippoMocks::mockFuncs<char,int>::static_expectation1<0,char *> (0D21DB1h)
```

If you watch the memory address 00D21C0D (may differ from run to run) in memory window, you will see, that  it gets patched after the call of ExpectCallFunc.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it in a moment, but can you explain the mechanism behind this? How does the call to `ParseStuff`in `myfunc.c` get redirected during the link phase? Well, I will take a look at the source code too, but I think it would be valuable to have this information. :)

Comment: [Holy mother of lord, what is this wizardry?](https://github.com/dascandy/hippomocks/blob/master/HippoMocks/hippomocks.h) O_o

Comment: @Lousy: The guy who wrote it, was a real wizard. :)))

Comment: Ok, this seems cool. Do you have experience with any lightweight unit testing framework which would go well with HippoMocks? Something lightweight, prefrerrably with JUnit XML support?

Comment: It is cool :)  A very lightweight testrunner is YAFFUT - comes with one header only and is much simpler to use as CppUnit for example.  In order to format the output in the right way, why don't you write a small script, which does the formatting stuff?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I can probably format it myself. So far I've tried Google Test because it's rather simple to use, supports automatic test registration and even has a plugin for Visual Studio. It's C++ too however, so I need to use `extern "C"` around header includes. Ok, thanks a lot, your answer solves most of my issues. I'll leave the bounty open for a couple of days, perhaps I can get some additional tips.

Answer (score 0):

I have not dealt with the C mocking libraries or Visual Studio, but I have thought about this in my own project. The [Feathers book](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WorkingEffectivelyWithLegacyCode) suggests the preprocessor seam or the link seam as a tool for dealing with this. You already mentioned the preprocessor seam, so I'll focus on the link seam.

The link seam requires the mocked function to be in a library, and the mock function to be in a library. The test can link against the mock function library while the target application can link against the original library.

Of course, as you mention, to mock MyFunc() you will have to create another library and a separate test application to link against it (or dynamically load and unload libraries in the test application).

It sounds quite laborious which is why I am procrastinating adding tests in my own application!

Hope this helps!